# Как извлечь длину аудиофайла с помощью PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, mediaplayer, qtmultimedia

Раньше я определял длину аудиофайла таким способом:

```
import datetime, mutagen

path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/music/13.Numb.mp3'
audiofile = mutagen.File(path)
length = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = audiofile.info.length))

print(length)
```

После этого цифры пишутся в базу данных.

Код действительно работает, но, когда мне потребовалось задействовать эту информацию в своем приложении, возникли проблемы.

**Первая проблема:**

Мое приложение воспроизводит музыкальные композиции. Чтобы определить, сколько секунд уже воспроизвелось, а сколько секунд осталось воспроизвести, я определяю длительность источника звука в `QMediaPlayer`.

Очень упрощенно вывод продолжительности источника выглядит так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia
import time

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.play_pause = True
        self.song = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/music/13.Numb.mp3'

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked = self.play)
        box.addWidget(play_btn)
    
        self.length = QtWidgets.QLabel('Length - 00:00', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        box.addWidget(self.length)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.play_mode)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def play(self):
        if self.play_pause == True:
            self.play_pause = False
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(self.song)))
            self.player.play()       

    def play_mode(self):
        if self.play_pause == False:
           self.length.setText(time.strftime('%M:%S', time.localtime(self.player.duration() / 1000)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Как оказалось данные в первом и втором коде разнятся. 
Иногда разница может достигать нескольких секунд. Для меня это довольно существенно, **поэтому хотелось бы сразу определять и сохранять длину трека посредством Qt.** 
К сожалению я не знаю, как это сделать, не добавляя аудиофайл в `QMediaPlayer`.

---

**Вторая проблема:**

Сейчас длина сохраняется в четырех цифрах. Две цифры выделяются на минуты, две другие выделяются на секунды. 
Выглядит это примерно так: **00:00**

Практически любая песня не достигает десяти минут. Т.е. в большинстве случаев нет необходимости во второй цифре в разделе минут.

Я бы хотел, обрезать первый нолик, если в четвертой цифре нет необходимости. Т.е. иногда строка должна выглядить так: **0:00**.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужны никакие `таймеры` и `time`

> QMediaPlayer::durationChanged(qint64 duration)
>
> Сигнал длительности контента изменился на длительность, выраженную в миллисекундах.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.play_pause = True
        self.song = 'D:/_Qt/__Qt/sound/sound_ringtimer.mp3'

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked = self.play)
        box.addWidget(play_btn)

        self.length = QtWidgets.QLabel('Length -      ', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        box.addWidget(self.length)

    def play(self):
        if self.play_pause == True:
            self.play_pause = False
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(self.song)))
            
            self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.time_duration)                     # +++
            
            self.player.play() 
            # self.player.setVolume(0.0)                      # убрать звук, если надо
                
    def time_duration(self, d):
        self.player.stop()                                    # +++ Останавливает воспроизведение медиа.
        m = d // 1000 // 60
        s = d // 1000 % 60
        self.length.setText(f'Length - {m:>1}:{s:0>2}')       # +++ форматируем строку вывода


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я добавлю в `QMediaPlayer` новый аудиофайл, это собъет музыку, которая могла играть во время добавления новых файлов в проигрыватель :(

Comment: @MAXIM045 уберите `self.player.stop()` , какие проблема ?

Comment: Возможно я что-то не пониманию. Вы задаете плееру новый источник, хотя подразумевалось, что в плеере уже была ссылка на файл, и он воспроизводил звук. Я планировал оставить возможность добавления новых файлов(во время добавления происходит запись в базу длины трека) параллельно с воспроизведением тех файлов, что уже были добавлены

Comment: @MAXIM045 я вас не понимаю. я не задаю плееру никаких новый источников. я только добавил `self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.time_duration)` и метод вывода строки в `Label`

Comment: Я попытаюсь объяснить лучше. Пожалуйста, не обижайтесь, если я где-то скажу очевидные вещи. У меня есть база данных. Она хранит информацию о песне, в том числе ее длину. При отображении списка песен рядом с названием каждой песни должна появиться ее длительность. Поэтому мне нужно определить длину песни до добавления ее в `QMediaPlayer`. Это будет происходить перебором каждого трека в какой-нибудь папки с жесткого диска компьютера. При этом в `QMediaPlayer` уже будет источник звука, т.е. параллельно будет воспроизводиться какая-то другая песня, отличная от той, длину которой нужно извлечь

Comment: Мне нужно просто получить переменную, содержащую строку с длиной песни. А уже потом я буду добавлять ее в базу данных. Прошу прощения, что не описал ситуацию полностью в вопросе. Я думал, так будет проще меня понять

Comment: Ни в коем случае не тороплю вас. Просто мне есть, что сказать. Давайте утром я задам новый вопрос, в котором объясню ситуацию подробнее? Говорю это, чтобы вы не тратили свое время на мой некорректный вопрос :)

Comment: @MAXIM045  Утро вечера мудренее :)